# AWS DynamoDB Stream example for App?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I used Firebase to create a chat app. But I plan to move the backend from google to AWS. I found that `DynamoDB` support a `Stream` function is very similar to Firebase in AWS Website.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

If someone adds a new message. Firebase and DynamoDB will notify clients the change. It is the basic feature of a chat app. Looks like `DynamoDB Stream` should be an alternative of Firebase.

But I notice that the documents and examples of `DynamoDB Stream` is very rare. And the weirdest is the tutorial has been removed

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-mobile-messaging-app-ios/?nc1=h_ls

Click `Get Started` will be redirected to `MobileHub`.

I wonder if the `DynamoDB Stream` function is not supported in the future? And this service will be replaced by `MobileHub`.

And I used another function of `MobileHub` in another app development. But not figure out how to use `MobileHub` to build a chatting function

If I want to use `AWS` to build a chat app. What is the best solution? Is any useful example or tutorial for `DynamoDB Stream`? Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks @Vijayanath Viswanathan

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would solve it,

These things are not yet wired up yet. Here is how you can do it.

DynamoDB (Streams) --> Lambda --> SNS

Subscribe to streams, changes will be delivered to your Lambda, you can customize how the message should look like and send notification with SNS.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is this still the best solution in 2019 for replicating Firebase realtime updat events?

Comment: Yes. It is still the way to go and very reliable. If you see any issues you can share here.